# Loader on PHP form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to establish a 'Loader' upon user submitting the form (PHP). Here's what I've got so far which doesn't seems to be working.

Can you please highlight where could be the potential issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#myForm').submit(function() {
       $('#loaderImg').show(); 
       return true;
     });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="" method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="loader1" style="display:none; height:30px; width:auto;" id="loaderImg">
        <input type="submit" id="clicknow" value="Click the button to go to another page">
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of the issues here is you are attempting to select elements before they are loaded into the DOM.  You can think of the document as being loaded into the DOM from the top to the bottom.  Your script is above the element that you are attempting to select and as such they are not in the DOM yet, so they cannot be acted upon yet.

There are two ways to fix this issue.  The first (and possibly easiest) is to simply move the script to the bottom of your page, right before `</body>`.  This will cause it to execute after the elements it is targeting are in the DOM.

Otherwise, if you want to leave it in the head you will need to use a document ready.

```
$(function(){
  $('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $('#loaderImg').show(); 
    return true;
  });
});
```

This will cause the logic inside to delay until the page has loaded all the markup into the DOM, at which point they will be available to be selected and interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

Load jquery library before scripting....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
     $('#loaderImg').show(); 
      return true;
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: *load jquery library* ?  If it wasn't loaded then his myForm attempt would fail.  Maybe rephrase?

Comment: I think you mean "Wait for the document to load before scripting"

Comment: That's not at all what your answer says.  Don't assume things. Clearly explain the issue and the solution.